# cufflinks don't show the plot with iplot

Tags: python, plot, cufflinks

I have this code where I need to get a plot and when I run the code, the plot just doesn't appears.
May someone help me please[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3kMs.png)
[This is the plot which should be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hAXD.png)
the code and the plot is from Python for finance cookbook, Eryk Lewinson.

I tried to just copy and paste the code from the book and it didn't work, the error was something about authentication and then I found a code to avoid this problem and still the plot doesn't appear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.